# Add attribute to detected keywords in ACE editor

Tags: ace-editor

I created a custom mode in ace editor for a custom markup I have in my app (which works great). I'd like to add a `contentEditable=false` for all the detected keywords.

Indeed, ace editor adds a `<span class="ace-keyword"> xxxx </span>` around the keywords but I need to add attributes to these spans. I have no idea where this should be done. Any insights?

Cheers

Comment: what do you want to accomplish with contentEditable=false? Ace doesn't use contentEditable attribute so it is false anyway

Comment: I'd like my keyword to be noneditable once written (in fact they are added by an extern script)